# Add editTexts to a layout dynamically using an add button in android

Tags: java, android, xml, layout, android-edittext

I am having a layout with a single editText in it,below the editText I added a add button. Now my question is when I click the add button I need to get another editText  below the editText and has to repeat the same.Please anyone help, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_edit_texts_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonAdd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ADD" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and put following code in your `Activity`

```
final LinearLayout llEditTextsContainer = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.ll_edit_texts_container);
        Button buttonAdd = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonAdd);
        buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                EditText editText = new EditText(getActivity());
                //editText.setId(); you should set id smartly if you wanted to use data from this edittext
                llEditTextsContainer.addView(editText);
            }
        });
```

Comment: @Ajay kumar did my answer help you?

Answer (score 1):

First of all create a container view in your main layout which is going to hold the new Edittexts.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.vuclip.dynamictextedit.MainActivity">

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/addTextView"
    android:text="Add EditText"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    />

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/containerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</TableLayout>
```

Here, on pressing the button, new Edittexts will be created and added into the TableLayout.

Now create a new Layout which will hold your edittext(I called this file new_layout.xml).

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/newEditText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
```

Now add this layout into your main activity.

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
TableLayout container;
static int rowIndex = 0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    container = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.containerLayout);
}

public void onClick(View view) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View newRowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_layout,null);
    container.addView(newRowView,rowIndex);
    rowIndex++;
}}
```